# Why RIP announce network does not need the mask?

Tags: router, network, rip

The below is the RIP protocol's declaring the routing command:

```
Router(config)#router rip 
Router(config-router)#version 2
Router(config-router)#network 1.1.1.1
Router(config-router)#network 192.168.12.0
Router(config-router)#exit
```

I want to know why the RIP protocol announcing the network, only wants the network IP address, but not the mask?

Comment: You should also use the `no auto-summary` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the protocol will check which interfaces belong to each subnet, and get the subnet mask from the interface configuration.

Check this [documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/fipr_c/1cfrip.html#wp1001118), it will help you understand the way it works